# Suggestion for owning a web server

Tags: hosting

I've written a web application in php for a school. The problem is its not feasible with shared hosting. And my client is not ready rent a dedicated server. So i have to get them a simple server. A tele communication company in my country is offering a static IP with 100Mbps speed and with a domain name for a business. And now my problem is i have 0 experience in this. Is a tower server enough to host a website that can handle about 100 requests at a time.  or should i prefer a rack server..? Also i would like to go for a cheaper OS and reduce cost..

Comment: Downvoted for a variety or reasons. There are umpteen amounts of questions asking about server recommendations, and they almost all get closed. It's also difficult to decipher what your actual question is in the above instance - you've been far too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too broad, apart from that, the difference between a rack and towerserver are almost nothing, except the case. A rack server is a loud machine meant to be placed in a room where no human comes often. A tower server is almost the same except it has a more silent case. Anyway I think a i7-930 or i7-2300k would do what you want it to do, build it yourself with 6 or 12 gb of memory ( depending on how much ur apache uses).

Cheaper OS :

- debian
- ubuntu
- centos

All free

I suggest you get apache2 webserver.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly your best bet is to find someone who has the experience in setting up the server and pay them to do it and you just deal with loading up your App. Give them your requirements and let them figure out the cheapest way to get there.